# how to configure solr4.10 for geo spatial search for polygon

Tags: solr, lucene, geospatial

Hi I want to configure solr4.10 for spatial search for polygon , I have do following changes
In schema.xml I have done changes as below

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
               spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
               distErrPct="0.025"
               maxDistErr="0.000009"
               units="degrees"/>
```

Actualy this entry already exist but does not contain spatialContextFactory so added this one also.

Now document which I am inserting is as below

```
<add>
<doc>
  <field name="id">3007</field>
  <field name="name">Autauga</field>
  <field name="coordinate">POLYGON((-10 30,-40 40,-10 -20,40 20,0 0,-10 30))</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

But when I try to insert the document with post.jar then it give exception as below

```
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file counties1.xml
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
</html>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
</html>
Time spent: 0:00:00.017
```

Please let me know where I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place jts-1.13 in solr-4.10.1/example/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib directory, now data will index fine